# Why am I dealing so little damage to enemies?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

Despite being several hours into the game, almost all the weapons I'm finding are still really weak. As such, I'm barely dealing any damage to the enemies I come across. Enemies on the other hand, often deal absurd amounts of damage against me. The imbalance has gotten so strong that I've just been avoiding combat all together.

I can only assume I'm doing something wrong, but I'm  not really sure what.

**Why am I  dealing so little damage to enemies?**

Comment: Posting this since I'm just assuming I'm not the only one that made the mistake of assuming **Fuse** was just intended to be an alternative to using Elixers for boosting your damage. It wasn't until I was several hours in that I finally realized weapon Fusing with monster parts is how the game scales my damage.

Comment: Skeleton arms make good, if not very durable, weapons in TotK.  Their base damage is 20 and if you fuse another skeleton arm to it, it's 40 total.  Pretty respectable, and fairly simple to farm, weapons.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that I'm not leveraging the **Fuse** ability. Once I started leveraging this ability, my damage problems went away.

Unlike in Breath of the Wild, the vast majority of the weapons you find are **Decayed** which means their damage is really low. You get around this issue by **Fusing** (mostly) monster parts to your weapons which will drastically increase their damage. The amount damage increased is indicated by the *Fuse Attack Power*, displayed directly underneath the item's name. Stronger monsters will drop parts with a larger attack bonus and you can usually tell which parts they'll drop (and how strong they are) based on their horn.

Comment: I'm maybe 25hrs in and even the non-decayed (pristine?) weapons I find are still very weak (especially compared to what you'd find in BotW). Base weapons in general have just seen huge nerfs in this game to compensate for fuse.

Comment: @scohe001 Weapons are so weak that I suspect during playtesting that testers ignored the Fuse mechanic, so weapons were heavily nerfed to make it clear you should be fusing.

Comment: You can also fuse the various things that Zonai enemies drop. Although these items can also be used for the gacha mechanic, their quality makes no difference in the number of device capsules you get, so you may as well use the higher-level ones for weapon improvements. Some of those items do a *lot* of fuse damage.

Comment: Step 1: Kill silver lynel.
Step 2: Pick up Silver Lynel Saber Horn (100 fuse attack power).
Step 3: Retrieve the Royal Guard's Claymore (74 damage) from beside the bell at the top of Hyrule Castle.
Step 4: Fuse the lynel horn to the claymore.
Step 5: Have fun with your OP 174 damage weapon.

Comment: I made this mistake.  I had to ask my brother how he was managing to collect monster parts, 'cause I couldn't kill anything.  He mentioned that he just kept fusing every new weapon to his old weapon.